# iText memory management - PdfReader/Watermarking loads too much

Tags: java, memory-management, itext, watermark

I'm watermarking documents, and I don't want to have to load them completely to memory, as they can be quite large. I found that RandomAccessFileOrArray that kind of buffers the reading, which it does fine but still loads too much to my liking.

That is, after I load a 5 Mb PDF file, the used memory increases 23Mb ! And when I start watermarking it it jumps another 27Mb ! After that used memory gradually increases, but not horribly.

Is there a reason to such behaviour ? Would you know a way to define the buffer size of the PdfReader or RandomAccessFileOrArray or something else ?

Thanks for your input.

---

The method printMem shows the status of the memory by showing free - used - total.

Here is my code

```
printMem("Before load");
    PdfReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(new FileInputStream("C:/TEMP/zip/100258.pdf")),null);
        printMem("After load");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, out);

        int numPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        int page=1;
        BaseFont baseFont = 
            BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE,
                BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        float width;
        float height;

        while (page <= numPages) {
            printMem("Page " + page);
            PdfContentByte cb = stamp.getOverContent(page);
            height = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(page).getHeight() / 2;
            width = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(page).getWidth() / 2;

            cb.saveState();
            cb.setColorFill(MEDIUM_GRAY);

            // Primary Text
            cb.beginText();
            cb.setFontAndSize(baseFont, PRIMARY_FONT_SIZE);
            cb.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, "WatermarkText", width,
                    height, TEXT_TILT_ANGLE);
            cb.endText();

            cb.restoreState();
            page++;
        }
        stamp.close();
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        reader = null;
        System.gc();
    }
```

And here is the partial output:

```
Before load | 1566248160 6615840 1572864000
After load | 1542392472 30471528 1572864000
Page 1 | 1515096880 57767120 1572864000
Page 2 | 1515095992 57768008 1572864000
Page 47 | 1512998840 59865160 1572864000
Page 48 | 1512998840 59865160 1572864000
```

Comment: Have you tried forcing garbage collection to see if it is really a memory leak, or if it is just that the memory has not freed?

Comment: Just a comment about memory usage and pdf size vs amount of pages. 
Memory usage is less dependent on the file size than on the number of pages. For instance: a one page PDF of 1Mb needs less memory than a 100 page pdf of 10 KB. Your code looks just fine with the partial read by RandomAccessFileOrArray.

Answer (score 3):

The document is only partially read if you construct the RandomAccessFileOrArray with a String which contains the path to the file (e.g. new RandomAccessFileOrArray("/path/to/pdf");). With an InputStream or a URL the whole document is copied to an internal byte array.